# Tell Netbeans to forget about SVN

Tags: svn, netbeans

Using Netbeans I once checked out a project from a SVN repository, just to test SVN functions in Netbeans.

Now, everytime I create a new project, or open an existing project not under source control, Netbeans "thinks" is under version control in that repository I was playing with.

How can I tell Netbeans to forget everything about that SVN repository I once used, so I can work on some small trivial applcation completely locally, without interacting with any version control repository. But without uninstalling Netbeans SVN plug-in so I can use for some other projects.

---

**Edit**: By *"Netbeans "thinks" is under version control in that repository"* I mean the following:

- In the project tree view a blue icon is shown next to almost all packages/objects
- Object names appear in green
- The tooltip on packages says *"Contains new, modified or deleted files or properties"*
- The tooltip on object says *"Locally modified"*
- SVN options to commit changes in the Team menu are available.

If I disable the SVN plugin, then all the above symptoms are gone.

On the other hand, I couldn't find any .svn subdirectory and no reference to svn in <%APPDATA%>/.netbeans/6.7/build.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED: There was a .svn directory *higher* in the directory tree, something like this:

```
c:\dir1
    |-\.svn
    |-\dir2
        |-\dir3 (where I store netbeans project)
            |-\project1
            |-\project2
            |   ...
            |-\projectN
```

Whenever I created a new project in c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\new_project the problem arised.

I removed that .svn directory ant the problems was solved.

Comment: I would note that once you do this, the projects which you have which ARE under svn's control that may be in some place like c:\dir1\dir2\MyProjectFromSVN are no longer under svn control... which may not be what folks expect/want...

The other strategy would be to create a new directory for 'unmanaged' projects, like c:\MyNonSVNProjects...

Comment: Thanks vkraemer, I'd noticed that and it's ok to delete that .svn direcotry because it was there since my first steps with svn client when messed everything up. +1 to your comment

Answer (score 10):

If you still need to keep your project under version control but maintain the version control outside NetBeans, you can deactivate SVN plugin or uninstall it completely. In the NetBeans IDE go to Tools->Plugins then under the Installed tab (in 7.x check in "Show details") check Subversion and hit Deactivate or Uninstall. The plugin will be deactivated/removed and you will be prompted to restart the IDE:
[image: how to disable NetBean Subversion Plug-in]

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so, not totally obvious:

1. Pre 7.1 (I think): disable svn module in `Tools` -> `Plugins`.
2. However, if svn is installed as part of the Base IDE: disconnect from svn via `Team` -> `Subversion` -> `Disconnect` ***while the root of svn checkout is selected***

Comment: Thanks. Yes you need to use Team-> if you install the full netbeans package. When I installed just the PHP version (7.1), then SVN can still be disabled from Tools->Plugins

Comment: Git highlighting enabled as soon as I disconnected from Subversion ^_^. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Netbeans "thinks" is under version
>   control in that repository I was
>   playing with.

How exactly does that manifest? The only thing that should make Netbeans think a project is version-controlled by SVN is the presence of an .svn subdirectory.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've just edited the question based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Team and click disconnect. This will disconnect you from GIT, netbeans showing this notification because you are connected to GIT.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file that Netbeans maintain, usually saved at "`C:\Documents and Settings\<login-Name>\.netbeans\5.5`" like location called build.properties. You can see if there are any SVN entries in that file, if so, back it up, delete those entries and see if this scenario repeats.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've just edited the question based on your answer.